# Delphi program to print a label in a Intermec PX4i

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to write a Delphi program to print a label in a Intermec PX4i. When I enter the commands in Fingerprint Terminal I can print the label, but not in my Delphi program.
Does some one has experience or examples?
My program doesn't raise any exception but it doesn't work :(
I would like to get some tips from a user with experience integrating a Intermec printer PX4i in a Delphi program.

The program I wrote is very basic:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonPrintLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Printer.Printers.Count = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('No printers available.');
    Exit;
  end;
  CustomPrintLabel;
end;

procedure TForm1.CustomPrintLabel;
var
  PrinterText: TStringList;
begin
  PrinterText := TStringList.Create;
  ShowMessage('Test2');
  try
    PrinterText.Add('BF ON:BF "Swiss 721 BT",6:PP 10,10:PX 430,340,15:PP 30,30:PM "GLOBE.1":PP 75,270:BT "CODE39":PB "ABC":PP 75,220:FT "Swiss 721 BT",6:PT "My FIRST label":PF ');

    Printer.Title := 'Print Job Title';
    Printer.BeginDoc;

    // Print the label text
    Printer.Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, PrinterText.Text);

    Printer.EndDoc;
  finally
    PrinterText.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What printer driver are you using? Don't draw on the printer canvas, it needs plain text!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment not to draw on the printer canvas and my own experience with Epson printer and ESC(Epson Standard Code) you could try something like this:

Sending raw bytes to the printer:

```
implementation

uses
  Vcl.Printers, Winapi.WinSpool;

procedure WriteRawData(const a: array of byte);
var
  phPrinter: THandle;
  pcWritten: DWORD;
  DocInfo: TDocInfo1;
begin
  // select your printer by name  - Vcl.Printers.Printer.Printers may help you
  if OpenPrinter(PChar('EPSON TM-T88V Receipt'), phPrinter, nil) then begin
    FillChar(DocInfo, SizeOf(DocInfo), 0);
    DocInfo.pDocName := 'Bondruck';
    DocInfo.pOutputFile := nil;
    DocInfo.pDatatype := 'RAW';
    if StartDocPrinter(phPrinter, 1, @DocInfo) > 0 then begin
      if StartPagePrinter(phPrinter) then begin
        WritePrinter(phPrinter, @a, Length(a), pcWritten);
        EndPagePrinter(phPrinter);
      end;
      EndDocPrinter(phPrinter);
    end;
    ClosePrinter(phPrinter);
  end;
end;
```

There should/could be better error handling with the `phPrinter` handle. For example with `RaiseLastOSError` in connection with the WinAPI calls.

And you could call this function like this:

```
begin
  // the encoding could be off, I don't know
  WriteRawData(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes('BF ON:BF "Swiss 721 BT",6:PP 10,10:PX 430,340,15:PP 30,30:PM "GLOBE.1":PP 75,270:BT "CODE39":PB "ABC":PP 75,220:FT "Swiss 721 BT",6:PT "My FIRST label":PF '));
end;
```